# In the first line/ on the first line

Tags: word-usage

Which one is correct:

On the first line of this page is written.

In the first line of this page is written.

Comment: Please note that neither of those is a complete sentence. If you want to know which is correct then you need to give complete sentences and also give sufficient context for us to decide which, if either of your sentences, is correct for that context.

Comment: I'm sure John Lawler would point out that you can choose _either_ the on-a-flat-surface or the container metaphor here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Here is some text. It forms the first line of this answer.**

If you look at that first line then you can say that:

**On** the first line of this answer is written the phrase, *"Here is some text. It forms the first line of this answer."*

Looking at that first line again, you can say that:

**In** the first line of this answer is written the word, 'forms'.

Comment: I'm so sorry. I don't understand what you mean. Would you please explain more?

Comment: I'll rewrite my answer. Apologies for making it self-referential.